# change text in android studio using viewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewbinding

I don't know why text is not changing in the BirthdayGreetingActivity.
No error is coming but it's not changing text. I checked(by Logcat) that name has came successfully to BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt from MainActivity.kt.

I guess that this [binding.birthdayGreeting.text = "Happy Birthday $name"] line in BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt is not working properly.

MainActivity.kt --

```
package com.example.firstapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.example.firstapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
    fun createBirthdayCard(view: View){
        val name = binding.nameInput.editableText.toString()
//        Toast.makeText(this,"Name is $name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val intent = Intent(this,BirthdayGreetingActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetingActivity.NAME_EXTRA,name)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt --

```
package com.example.firstapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.firstapp.databinding.ActivityBirthdayGreetingBinding

class BirthdayGreetingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityBirthdayGreetingBinding

    companion object{
        const val NAME_EXTRA ="name_extra"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityBirthdayGreetingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday_greeting)

        val name = intent.getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA)
//        val greet = binding.birthdayGreeting.editableText.toString()
//        print(name)
//        if (name != null) {
//            Log.d("greet = ",binding.birthdayGreeting.editableText.toString())
//        }
        binding.birthdayGreeting.text = "Happy Birthday $name" [maybe something wrong here]
    }
}
```

:) :) Thanks for spending your valuable time to help me :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On BirthdayGreetingActivity you are passing the layout ID for **setContentView**, instead you must pass the **binding.root**, just like you did on MainActivity...

Change this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday_greeting)
```

To:

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```